# How to make two tables Work together SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have 2 tables
Table1&Table2
Table1 Contains this Field

1) Field_ID

2) Field_Machine_name

3) Field_Date

And

Table2 Contains this Field

1) Field_ID

2) Field_Machine_name

3) Field_Date_Add

How can I make Field_Machine_name In Table 1
work together with Table 2 in FieldMachine_name

I Want to add a record in Table 1 and automatically its added to Table 2

Until now I have to do it manually in Table 2 So that it Not worth

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: Is Field_ID of table1 as Foreign key in table2?

Answer (score 0):

not much clear with question...think on writing trigger on table 1.So when insert happens in Table 1 it will insert record in table 2 too..